# how do multiple raspberry pi node talk to each other if I connect two raspberry pi nodes two a switch?

Tags: linux, networking

how do they get the ip addresses? assuming if I have dhcp enable on them. I know they can get the addresses via router. But what about swiches. Do I have to assign addresses manually?

Comment: I recommend reading the CCNA study materials.

Comment: I just want to verify all of of my assumption, before deploy a cluster. I need the nodes realize the interfaces of each other.

Comment: "I" is always uppercase on English.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a DHCP server handing out addresses, you will have to assign static addresses to both Paspberry Pis. The addresses have to be assinged from the same subnet, i.e. the network part the addresses have to be equal.

If both RPis have automatically configured IPv4 link-local addresses, they can use these addresses to communicate with each other. The link-local addresses can be recgnized by that they are chosen from the `169.254.0.0/16` prefix. Interfaces are normally not configured to use these addresses if some other address is assigned, and not always even if no other address is available. (This depends on the Linux distribution.) Another problem with IPv4 link-local addresses is that they are dynamic, i.e. they are not guaranteed to stay the same over a reboot.

Finally, you can use IPv6 link-local addresses, which start with `fe80:`. The IPv6 link-local addresses are static and always assigned (unless you have disabled IPv6), but they have the problem that they are long and hard to remember. This can be worked around by adding entries for them in `/etc/hosts`. IPv6 link-local addresses are also a bit problematic if there are several network interfaces on the host, because a destination link-local address does not contain information on via which interface the remote host is reachable. This means that often the you will have to specify an interface in in addition to the IP address when connecting.

Answer (score 0):

A switch doesn't have an IP address - it just sends packets to the devices which are connected to it without modifying anything at the IP level.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are correct, imho, but they miss a thing or two.

A switch does not usually assign IP addresses (DHCP server), however, a router that has a switch  or a router connected to a switch with DHCP server enabled will assign IP addresses to all devices connected to the switch. Since I do not know your network topology, I cannot tell precisely.

You can usually configure the router to assign static ip addresses to your raspberry's, that is what I do, all you need for the is the hardware address (aka MAC address, nothing to do with the fruity firm) ... you can get the MAC address by issuing `sudo ifconfig` on the pi's, it also lists their IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. (IPv4 is like `192.168.1.123`, IPv6 `2a01:e34:ee38:....` [those are the addresses I have, you might have others], link local IPv6 addresses [local to your network] start with `fe80::` [we all have link local addresses like this if IPv6 is configured])

I have my DSL router configured to assign IP addresses in the range 1-200, IP addresses above 200 are "servers", systems that need a static IP address - these I use for static IP addresses.

I configure the router to assign a specific address to a specific "server" device, using the MAC address, this way I do not need to configure the device, I can nuke the OS from orbit, install another and still, it gets the same IP address.

I am lucky, my DSL router lists all devices on the network, so I can identify the pi's pretty easily.